# Flutter app doesn't run. It gives this type of Error

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

- Error running Gradle:
  ProcessException: Process "/var/www/html/Happy/Flutter/demo/android/gradlew" exited abnormally:

> Configure project :app
>   Observed package id 'build-tools;debian' in inconsistent location '/usr/lib/android-sdk/build-tools/27.0.1' (Expected
>   '/usr/lib/android-sdk/build-tools/debian')
>   Observed package id 'build-tools;debian' in inconsistent location '/usr/lib/android-sdk/build-tools/27.0.1' (Expected
>   '/usr/lib/android-sdk/build-tools/debian')
>   Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 in /usr/lib/android-sdk/licenses
>   Warning: License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 not accepted.
>   Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 26 in /usr/lib/android-sdk/licenses
>   Warning: License for package Android SDK Platform 26 not accepted.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '/var/www/html/Happy/Flutter/demo/android/build.gradle' line: 26
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

  > A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
  >   Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
  >       platforms;android-26 Android SDK Platform 26
  >       build-tools;28.0.3 Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3
  >    To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK
  >    Manager.
  >    Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see
  >    http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

  Using Android SDK: /usr/lib/android-sdk
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to
  get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
  Command: /var/www/html/Happy/Flutter/demo/android/gradlew app:properties

Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` and then accept all licenses